# How to take this integral? $\int \frac{dx}{x\ln x\ln (\ln x)}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Have this small, but beautiful integral:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x\ln x\ln (\ln x)}$$

Comment: Do you know the last words of a number theorist before drowning? They are $\log\log\log$.

Comment: Very happy that you possess such an integral. Then what else ? ... You should at least say what you have tried...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: ;-D ;-D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**

You should notice that :

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln(\ln(x))\right)=\frac{\frac 1x}{\ln(x)}=\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}$$

Comment: Nice observation!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can do repeated substitution of $\ln$. Substituting $u=\ln(x)$ gives:
$$\int \frac{1}{u\cdot \ln{u}}~du$$
You can substitute $v=\ln{u}$, and from here on, it should be extremely easy.